# QMouseEvent::pos() returns different values on different OSes

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets, qmouseevent, qt5.15

I have created a simple example which is just a window with a red rectangle. This rectangle has 50px margins from top, bottom, right and left. The value of 50px is definitely hardcoded and cannot be changed from the application.

The (0,0) point of the widget is located in the left-top corner. That means, that when I click on the left-top corner of the red rectangle (a little bit pixel hunting, but that's OK), I anticipate to click to the position with the coordinates of (50,50).

But, for a reason that I cannot understand:

- It is true on **Windows** only.
- On **Linux** I get (51, 51), a single pixel shift.
- On MacOS I get (52, 52), a two pixels shift.

Is that a known behavior? Or how could I fix it?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

#include <QPainter>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(800, 600);
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* me) {
    auto pos = me->pos();
    qDebug() << "pos: " << pos.x() << "," << pos.y();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QPainter p(this);
    p.fillRect(50, 50, width() - 100, height() - 100, Qt::red);
    p.setPen(Qt::black);
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* me) override;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe) override;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**incorrect_pos_on_different_os.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

CONFIG += console

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

This problem is reproducible on Qt 5.15.2 (that's pretty old, I know, but I cannot upgrade it right now, I need to use what I have).

I use:

- I use Qt 5.15.*
- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 20.04
- MacOS Monterey

Comment: Please [edit] your code to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'd guess the widgets are simply in different places on each os depending on control styling and dpi settings

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: @AlanBirtles _different places_ shouldn't count: [QPoint QMouseEvent::pos() const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#pos) _Returns the position of the mouse cursor, relative to the widget that received the event._

Comment: @Scheff'sCat depends what they mean by "the same point", controls could have different borders or padding resulting in different results

Comment: Have you considered that every OS possibly shows "same" widgets in different ways, possibly with different borders, margins, paddings, spacings, etc.? Have you considered to take a screenshot of that windows on all OS, comparing sizes and distances between elements?

Comment: Could you use [this](https://hastebin.com/share/romecibabu.cpp) even shorter [mre]? I tested on Linux Fedora KDE spin with Qt 5.15.2, Qt 6.6.0 and Qt 6.6.1 and I can reproduce the (51,51) mouseEvent position when clicking on the white pixel (I used KMag and drew a 3x3 red square with a white pixel at the center to ease the pixel hunting). I also used `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and got the same result.

Comment: I also used `setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Windows"))` on both the QApplication and the widget, same result. These are just "blind" attempts based on the other comments that could perhaps help clarify, I don't understand the issue.